# How to hide or prevent an antd submenu to be rendered?

Tags: reactjs, hide, acl, antd

I have a `Menu` as bellow:

```js
<Menu>
  <SubMenu>
   <Menu.Item>Help</Menu.Item>
   <Menu.Item>Antd</Menu.Item>
  </SubMenu>
</Menu>
```

Now the problem is that I need to hide `SubMenu` or `Menu.Item` for some situations? something like below :

```js
<Menu>
  <Acl item="submenu">
    <SubMenu>
      <Acl item="help">
        <Menu.Item>Help</Menu.Item>
      </Acl>
      <Menu.Item>Antd</Menu.Item>
    </SubMenu>
  </Acl>
</Menu>
```

The `Acl` component will check for user access to the menu and decide to hide or show the text.

Is there any code examples for `antd` to reach this result or any suggestions?

Note: Already I have implemented `Acl` as bellow:

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class Acl extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }
  render() {
    const props = this.props;
    if( hasAccess(props.item) )
      return <div>{props.children}</div>;
    return null;
  }
}

export default Acl;
```

But after render I got this error: 

`Cannot read property 'indexOf' of undefined`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it could be done as bellow:

```js
render() {
  const { getAccessByPath } = this.props; //selector from redux store
  <Menu>
  { getAccessByPath('submenu') ?
    <SubMenu>
     { getAccessByPath('submenu.help') ? 
         <Menu.Item>Help</Menu.Item> : ''
     }
     <Menu.Item>Antd</Menu.Item>
    </SubMenu> : ''
  }
  </Menu>
}
```

This works now but is so nasty and is not readable if I have more submenus an menu items (currently about 20) but I think there should be a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`disabled` prop](https://ant.design/components/menu/#Menu.Item) of `Menu.Item` and `Menu.Submenu` and use it to disable the button according to user type:

```
<Menu.Item disabled={userAccess()}>    // userAccess() should return a boolean
```

In case you want to totally hide the button, you need to use conditional rendering, of the sort:

```
<Menu>
  <Acl item="submenu">
   { (userAccess()) ?          // again should return boolean
    <SubMenu>
      <Acl item="help">
        <Menu.Item>Help</Menu.Item>
      </Acl>
      <Menu.Item>Antd</Menu.Item>
    </SubMenu> : ''
   }
  </Acl>
</Menu>
```

Comment: thanks, I think this won't work by the reason that I added to question. please see the last update.

Comment: do you know which line is throwing that error ? Is it thrown from inside the Ant component ? Can you share the code for `hasAccess()` as well ?